# How can I use v-if dynamically with Nuxt.js generate?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

If I wrote this .vue file, v-if is resolved when I run `nuxt generate` command.
But I want to use dynamic v-if.
How can I do this?

```
<template>
  <div v-if="foo()"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods:{
    foo:function(){ 
      /*
      this method return boolean. 
      now, this is called at `nuxt generate
      but I want to run this when user visit page` 
      */ 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why not creating a data property like `show` then mutate it when foo is called?

Comment: Thank you. But it did not work. I made 404.vue in page directory and set fallback:true for netlify.  then, run `nuxt generate` and Nuxt.js generate dist/404/404.html.  I wrote this code in 404.vue but v-if does not work in  generated html file. If `show` was true when I run `nuxt generate`, It just include contents. If `show` was false , It is comment outed like `<!-- -->`. But I want to use v-if dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use vue lifecycle named 'mounted'. Create a data named for example 'isMounted' and set it to true.

```
data() {
  return {
    isMounted: true
  }
}
```

then use it in your html as:

```
<div v-if="isMounted"></div>
```

Then change its value in the mounted lifecycle as follows:

```
mounted(){
 this.isMounted = this.foo();
}
```